# How to completely remove an empty element from an array with JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

When using JBuilder, how I can completely remove evidence of an empty array element from my output? For this code sample, assume that we have three users and the third user has a `nil` address:

```
json.array! @users.each do |user|
  unless user.address.nil?
    json.name user.name
    json.address user.address
  end
end
```

The resulting JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Rob",
    "address":"123 Anywhere St."
  },
  {
    "name":"Jack",
    "address":"123 Anywhere St."
  },
  {}
]
```

See that last, empty `{}` at the end there. So any time the block passed to `array!` returns `nil` I end up with an empty element in the array, rather than a lack of element. Is there any easy way to tell JBuilder not to output those? Or do I just need to treat the output of `array!` as a plain ol' array and then `compact` or `reject` elements that I don't want?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid your use case by first using [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) on the users, and only add the valid users to the array:

```
json.array! @users.reject { |user| user.address.nil? }.each do |user|
  json.name user.name
  json.address user.address
end
```

Comment: Yep, I could totally do that, which is how I'm handling the problem right now. And of course I shouldn't have this logic in the view anyway. ;) But I was just wondering that if/when this situation does arise if there was a way for `array!` to handle this case for me...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `select` instead of `each`, it will return a value only for non-nil elements

```
json.array! @users.select do |user|
  unless user.address.nil?
    json.name user.name
    json.address user.address
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not worried about the user being nil in this case, just one of its properties. You're right, I would not want to include nil users, but the behavior I'm seeing is that if the block itself returns nil (in this case when user.address is nil) then I get an empty {} instead of nothing at all.